# Can you dye the costumes?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

Can you dye the costumes (Ezio's Costume, the Pirate Kidd Costume) and others or is the colour on them permanent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot change the color of outfits other than your basic assassin robes. You can buy recolors of your basic outfit from merchants.

Answer (score 2):

Building on kotekzot answer:

The recolours are listed on the **outfits section** of the **buy menu** for the traders.

You can buy every recolour (outfit) and then go back and choose another one just buy pressing the button to select it (A button in xbox/pc with xbox controller).

This is the same behaviour as you find with the weapons on the trader menu!

I was actually expecting that these outfits would be selectable from the wardrobe in the secret room in the homestead. But no!